# How can I use a service on a class that already extends other class?

Tags: java, android, android-service, extends

I have a class that i want to use as a service, but my class already extends other class and as a result I cant extend from multiple classes. Is there a way to use this class as a service while it also extends from other class?

Comment: take this as a hint to decouple your code. One class is not supposed to be doing 2 things

Comment: name the class you are already extending

Comment: FragmentActivity

Answer (score 0):

You can't extends multiple classes in to one directly their are some tricky ways one of them is defined below:

```
public class CustomActivity extends Activity {

     private SecondClass myClass;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         myClass = new SecondClass(this);
     }

     //Implement each method you want to use.
     public String getInfoFromOtherClass()
     {
        return myClass.getInfoFromOtherClass();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is Interface.**Multiple inheritance is not possible in Java due to Diamond problem.**

You should do something like:

```
public class Main extends Service implements OtherClass
```

[This](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/patterns/multipleinheritance.html) will give you a clear idea